# Clear fixing toggling text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have toggle image and next to image I put some text. with float.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $(".question-hide").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#btn1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#click-button-text {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main-frame">
    <div class="frame-wrapper">
      <img class="idea-image" src="img/idea.png">

      <img id="btn1" src="img/button1.png" alt="button image">
      <p id="click-button-text">
        をクリックするとアンサーがご覧になれます。</p>
      <p class="question-hide">Text is right below the button</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but with this float - the text in the toggle floating to the left too.

**Todo :**

So I want it be right below to toggle button. 
But i couldn't figure it out to clear fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so because the text's container `(<p id="click-button-text">)` width is not 100%
So it is taking the remaining space, make it 100% to bring it down.

I would recommend using a framework like `bootstrap` for grid structure.

Note: there can be many more approaches to this, i have provided the quick fix

Run the code to see:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $(".question-hide").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
#btn1 {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#click-button-text {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="main-frame">
        <div class="frame-wrapper">
            <img class="idea-image" src="img/idea.png">

            <img id="btn1" src="img/button1.png" alt="button image"> 
            <p id="click-button-text">をクリックするとアンサーがご覧になれます。</p>
                <p class="question-hide">Text is right below the button</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one more question about this. My Japanese text is going under too. I am using inline block but not effective

Comment: Can you create an example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: actually I solved the problem, but thank you for answering back.